# can httpd run php-script as specific user

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

My server has a couple of users in it. I am running httpd with php support.

Now all users can make php-script and open it with their browser and run it as *www-data*. Because of this, it is impossible to make php-script not accessible by others and everyone is able to see each others SQL-passwords etc. if they wish.

Is there any way to run those php-scripts as owner of the file? Or another suggestion how to secure the situation. I've been studying Apache Virtual hosts as a possible solution but with no luck. suPHP would probably do the trick but no longer available from repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is `mpm-itk` apache module, which allows to run each of virtual host under a separate uid and gid. But the solution isn't acceptable for pure nginx installations.

Another and better in my opinion solution is to switch to `php-fpm` which can run multiple separate pools each with its own uid/gid. Read [this](https://gist.github.com/fyrebase/62262b1ff33a6aaf5a54) kindly.

Comment: Best solution so far as I didn't have to install apache! I've used lighttpd until now and I've had urls like example.com/~user however I don't know if they are possible with this setup. So I just added virtual hosts like virtual1.example.com and virtual2.example.com and they work as intended.

Comment: Seems it is possible, if someone is looking for such solution. Haven't tested though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753975/multiple-fpm-socket-in-one-nginx-site-by-locations

Answer (score 2):

This is well-known problem that can be solved using mpm-itk apache module which is specifically intended for running scripts in virtual hosts with the rights of their owners (http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).

This module is prebuilt into hosting administration packages such as ISPmanager and so on. I'd recommend using such packages to get rid of boring ajustments of your server because all can be done in a few minutes.